# Pandas speed calculation based on travelled distance and time

Tags: python, pandas, latitude-longitude, haversine

I have the following dataframe:

```
data = [
    [ID, '2022-04-23T03:36:26Z', 60, 10, 83],
    [ID, '2022-04-23T03:37:30Z', Nan, Nan, Nan],
    [ID, '2022-04-23T03:37:48Z', Nan, Nan, Nan],
    [ID, '2022-04-23T03:38:24Z', 61, 11, 72],
    [ID, '2022-04-23T03:44:20Z', 63, 13, 75],
    [ID, '2022-04-23T03:45:02Z', Nan, Nan, Nan],
    [ID, '2022-04-23T03:45:06Z', Nan, Nan, Nan],
    [ID, '2022-04-23T03:45:08Z', Nan, Nan, Nan],
    [ID, '2022-04-23T03:45:12Z', Nan, Nan, Nan],
    [ID, '2022-04-23T03:45:48Z', 69, 15, 61]
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data,
                  columns=['ID', 'time', 'latitude', 'longitude', 'speed')
```

The problem is that for some rows I have only the time value e.g. row 2 and 3. **For these rows, I want to calculate the average speed based on time, latitude and longitude of the row preceding (row 1) and following (row 4) the Nan speed rows**.

For example, the speed value in row 2 and 3 should be an average speed value which is based on the travelled distance (maybe using Haversine formula) divided by the total amount of time ('2022-04-23T03:38:24Z' - '2022-04-23T03:36:26Z').

How can I write this in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`pandas.DataFrame.interpolate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html#pandas.DataFrame.interpolate) may be what you're looking for if you're looking for a naive approach *(there's other options if you're looking for something more specific just see the docs)*:

```
df[["latitude", "longitude", "speed"]] = df.interpolate() \
    [["latitude", "longitude", "speed"]].round().astype(int)
```

Result:

```
ID                  time  latitude  longitude  speed
0  ID  2022-04-23T03:36:26Z        60         10     83
1  ID  2022-04-23T03:37:30Z        60         10     79
2  ID  2022-04-23T03:37:48Z        60         10     75
3  ID  2022-04-23T03:38:24Z        61         11     72
4  ID  2022-04-23T03:44:20Z        63         13     75
5  ID  2022-04-23T03:45:02Z        64         13     72
6  ID  2022-04-23T03:45:06Z        65         13     69
7  ID  2022-04-23T03:45:08Z        66         14     66
8  ID  2022-04-23T03:45:12Z        67         14     63
9  ID  2022-04-23T03:45:48Z        69         15     61
```